# window.addEventListener('beforeunload' not working in chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, addeventlistener

when browser or tab close I need to send logout request to server and im using following code . Its working in all browsers except chrome.

```
 function httpGetLogout(url)
    {
        var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlHttp.open( "GET", url, false ); // false for synchronous request
        xmlHttp.send( null );
        return xmlHttp.responseText;
    }
    
    function autoLogout(){
            window.addEventListener('beforeunload', function (e) {
                httpGetLogout('/logout');
                e.preventDefault();
                e.returnValue = '';
            });
    }
```

Comment: Synchronous XHR is deprecated. Also, the `beforeunload` event may never fire. It's not recommended to rely on it.

Comment: Thanks D. Pardal, I have tried 'onbeforeunload' also still same issue in chrome browser.